# Retreive current user data without reload the page - React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, react-hooks

I'm trying to get current user in drawer of react navigation by using AsyncStorage so when I login the function doesn't invoked till I refresh the page two times even I call it in the useEffect fun, May someone help me to solve this issue please!

**Drawer Component:**

```
import {
    DrawerContentScrollView,
    DrawerItem
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

    const [email, setEmail] = useState()
    const [items, setItems] = useState({})
    
     useLayoutEffect(() => {
    
    
   getCurrentUser()
   
}, [])

const getCurrentUser = async() => {

    try {

        AsyncStorage.getItem("userName", (err, result) => {
            setEmail(result)
       });

      await AuthService.getCurrentUser(email)
        .then(response => {

            setItems(response.data);
           // setLabel(items.firstName.charAt(0)+items.lastName.charAt(0))

        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });

        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
        
}
<Provider>
            <View>
                <DrawerContentScrollView>

                    <View>
                        <View>
                            <View>
                                <Avatar.Text
                                    label='{items.firstName}'
                                    size={52}
                                    color='white'
                                />


<View>
<Title> {items.firstName} {items.lastName}
  </Title>

      <Caption>{email}</Caption>
         </View>...
```

**App.js:**

```
<PaperProvider>
          <NavigationContainer>
          
              <Drawer.Navigator
              initialRouteName="LoginScreen"
              screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                headerTransparent:true
              }}
              drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
          ....
```

**Error:**

> Request failed with status code 404 at
> node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:14 in createError at
> node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:22 in settle at
> node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:66:12 in onloadend at
> node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 i..

So here is the whole code, I'm trying to get data of current user and display it on the header of the drawer navigation.

Comment: Hi, are you getting the user every time you open the drawer menu? Can you post this whole file?

Comment: @JunDeLeon No I get only the useContext variable I should refresh my drawer page to get user s data

Comment: I see, but I need more information in order to help you, because I do not know if you are using react drawer navigation, or it is just a component or a customhook you create with the name drawerMenu, I can't even see what are you returning.

Comment: @JunDeLeon Okay I updated my question you can check it now